# How do I call an AuthenticationService from a login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have a solution with 2 projects. In the first project a I have a website with a Logon Control. In the second project I have a WCF project with an AuthenticatonService configured. What is the easiest way to integrate both? In other word, How do I call the Authentication Service from the login control?

EDIT:

OK, what I mean is that by default, you can set the *MembershipProvider* property in a login control for authentication.  This property refers to a locally defined provider in machine.config or web.config.

what I want is to stop using that provider defined locally and call the remote WCF authentication service instead.  Sorry for not making myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

Finally I got it working.  This is what I did:

- Add a Service Reference to the WCF url:

  http://localhost:8080/servicios/MiServicio.svc
- Resetted the Membership Provider property of the Login control.  This in facts look for the default membershipprovider installed with VS 2008 (SQLEXPRESS).
- implement the Authenticate event.  This has to be done in order to override the default behavior of authenticating with the default membership provider and do a custom authentication.  In this event, create an instance of the proxy authenticationservice class and call Login method.

`proteted void login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgse){
   AuthenticationServiceClient client = new AuthenticationServiceClient();
   e.Authenticated = client.Login(login.UserName, login.Password, "", true);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [Exposing WCF Services to Client Scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961.aspx)

Comment: Thanks,  I went through that tutotorial already.  Although it helped me configuring my authentication service, it does not show how to call the service from a remote website(i.e a login control)

Comment: If it's a web service you need only publicly expose it for a remote website to use it.  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479031.aspx) that calls your Authentication service during the ValidateUser method.

The AuthenticationService allows you to use the ASP.NET Membership system to authenticate users in other applications - rather than providing a mechanism for authenticating users on the website itself.

Comment: Yes, I undesrtand.  What I was trying to do is make the Login control use the WCF AuthenticationService.